# Llamar a metodos desde mi main

Tags: java, eclipse

tengo un proyecto con formato mvc en el cual tengo que recorrer un archivo csv, tomar cada linea, separar los campos y mostrarlos por pantalla. Instanciar un objeto por cada linea  que pueda registrar los campos necesarios y que exponga un método imprimir() donde muestre esos valores.

Mi proyecto esta dividido en packages
-principal
donde esta mi main
-service
donde se encuentra la interfaz y una clase donde se implementan el metodo  de esa interfaz
-model
donde se encuentra la clase Vial, la cual tiene los atributos, los get y set de cada uno de ellos ya que mi archivo Vial es un csv donde almaceno los datos de mi csv y separo en objetos de clase vial.
Ya realice mi modelo, pero tengo dudas acerca de mi service y mi main.
Yo el proyecto ya hice todo el código, pero solo quiero que desde mi main llame al metodo imprimir que se encuentra en el service, que este llame al serviceimp que implementa dicho metodo en el service y se muestre lo pedido, pero no se como hacerlo.
Mi idea seria que quede en mi main
un método leer que lea el archivo
leerarchivo que liste los objetos que se almacenaron en Vial
y por ultimo un metodo imprimir() que muestre los archivos que hay en el csv.

```
File sFile = new File("C:\\Users\\leand\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\GitHub\\delrioc1-clase1\\vial.csv");
    FileReader sFileReader = null;
    try {
        sFileReader = new FileReader(sFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(sFileReader);
    String linea = "";
    List<Vial> sList = new ArrayList<Vial>();
    
    try {
        try {
            while((linea = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String [] array = linea.split(",");
                    Vial sVial = new Vial(Integer.parseInt(array[0]),array[1],Integer.parseInt(array[2]),array[3],Integer.parseInt(array[4]));
                    sList.add(sVial);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    //System.out.println("NºHOJA"+" "+"TIPO OBJETO"+" "+"IDENTIFICADOR TRAMO"+" "+"TIPO CAMINO"+" "+"Km");
    
        for (Vial vial : sList) {
            System.out.println("NºHOJA/"+" "+"/TIPO-OBJETO"+" "+"/IDENTIFICADOR-TRAMO"+"  "+"/TIPO-CAMINO"+"     "+"/KM");  
            System.out.println(vial.getId()+"     "+vial.getDescripcion() +"            "+vial.getNumero()+"        "+vial.getRuta()+"   "+ vial.getKm());
        }
```

> Cita en bloque

Me ayudaria muchisimo si pudieran sacarme las dudas ya que ver el código resuelto me guiaria porque me maree un poco y no se como desde mi main, llamar al service y que el mismo llame a sus métodos en serviceimp.

Answer (score 0):

en tu clase "main" deberás crear con 'new' por ejemplo un nuevo "Vial":

```
Vial v = new Vial();
```

A partir de aquí puedes llamar a todos los métodos de tu clase Vial donde tendrás el de imprimir (siempre que tu método sea "public"):

```
v.imprimir();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no lo vi como crear un objeto de mi clase y de ahi llamar a su método.